# ListView bad scrolling performance and freezing

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I have a `ListView` with `VirtualizingStackPanel` as `ItemsPanelTemplate`
and it hosts hundreds of thumbnails (I know it is usually bad UX but this is how people use this app)

In order to minimize memory usage I am keeping only path to thumbnail in my model, and convert it to image when it is scrolled into view with iValueConverter.

The performance is really bad, making UI unresponsive, and it even happened that app would freezes after some up and down scrolling.

```
 <Image Source="{Binding Filename, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" />
```

and converter

```
 public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            string FileName = value as string;            
            var file = Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(FileName).AsTask().Result;
            var stream = file.OpenReadAsync().AsTask().Result;
            var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
            return bitmapImage;
        }
```

Is there a better way? User may scroll one page, jump to the middle, or scroll the whole list, so I think it would not make sense to preload BitmapImages in model. If I do that scrolling is smooth but app memory footprint goes 1GB+ which is unacceptable.

WPF used to have `IsAsync=true` for binding but that is not available for UWP.

Comment: What is the file type?

Comment: @DavidOliver jpg

Comment: Any reason why you use a `VirtualizingStackPanel`? You should stick with `ItemsStackPanel` for a much better performance.

Comment: @JustinXL I guess it was a habit from WPF days and I thought it is not virtualizing if we are not using `VirtualizingStackPanel` but the performance is much better and both take the same amount of RAM.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're carrying out multiple heavy operations on the UI thread:

```
        var file = Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(FileName).AsTask().Result;
        var stream = file.OpenReadAsync().AsTask().Result;
        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
```

If you consider that you're multiplying this by every single thumbnail that appears when you scroll the list rapidly, obviously you're seeing performance issues. The app freeze you're seeing may be because you're blocking on async methods using `Task.Result`, which can easily lead to [deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Even though the `SetSource` method isn't async, it's also costly.

I assume you're reading a stream and calling `SetSource` from [permissions concerns](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/6aad3d1b-1807-45a4-a5b0-3365df74e33d/absoluteuri-winrt-load-image-in-runtime?forum=winappswithcsharp&forum=winappswithcsharp). If you can simply bind `Image.Source` directly to the path string, that's by far the best approach.

Otherwise, you'll need to create a custom behaviour to set the source asynchronously. Here's a rough outline:

```
public static class ImageSourceStreamBehavior
{
    private static CancellationTokenSource GetCTS(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (CancellationTokenSource)obj.GetValue(CTSProperty);
    }

    private static void SetCTS(DependencyObject obj, CancellationTokenSource value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(CTSProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CTSProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CTS", typeof(CancellationTokenSource), typeof(ImageSourceStreamBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public static string GetSource(Image obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(SourceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSource(Image obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(SourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Source", typeof(string), typeof(ImageSourceStreamBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null,
            (o, e) => OnSourceChanged((Image)o, (string)e.NewValue)));

    private static void OnSourceChanged(Image image, string newValue)
    {
        GetCTS(image)?.Cancel();
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        SetCTS(image, cts);

        SetSourceAsync(cts.Token, image, newValue);
    }

    private static async Task SetSourceAsync(CancellationToken ct, Image image, string fileName)
    {
        var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(fileName).AsTask(ct);

        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) { return; }

        var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync().AsTask(ct);

        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) { return; }

        if (image.Source == null)
        {
            image.Source = new BitmapImage();
        }
        await ((BitmapImage)image.Source).SetSourceAsync(stream);
    }
}
```

Since items in a list get recycled, the idea is that applying the previous image will be cancelled if the image is scrolled out of view before it's fully displayed. Also, you're no longer blocking the UI thread.

You would use it as follows:

```
<Image ImageSourceStreamBehavior.Source="{Binding Filename}"/>
```

Also, as Justin XL points out, you should use `ItemsStackpanel` unless you have a compelling reason not to.

Comment: And in case it's not clear, the really bad thing that you should "never" do in the UI is call `.AsTask().Result` -- that's the call that is hanging your app.

Comment: The issue with this code is that every about 3 pages I am getting the same images repeating even though the Source is different